# DataTables custom column parameter for order - Ajax

Tags: ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

Is it possible to pass different type of column/cell content for sort type for all columns/cells? I don't want to define for which column this rule apply. I call the same DataTable object on multiple tables with different structure.

**JS:**

```
$(".dataTable").DataTable({
    "ajax": ajaxURL,
    "deferRender": true,
    "lengthMenu": [
         [5, 15, 20, 50, -1],
         [5, 15, 20, 50, "All"] // change per page values here
    ],
    "pageLength": 15,
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": "_all",
        "data": null,
        "render": {
            "_": "plain",
            "filter": "filter",
            "display": "plain"
        }
    }]
});
```

**JSON response:**

```
{"data":[
    [
       {"plain":122,"filter":122},
       {"plain":"waiting","filter":0},
       {"plain":"27.12.2015","filter":"1451174400"}
    ],[
       {"plain":123,"filter":123},
       {"plain":"approved","filter":1},
       {"plain":"27.12.2015","filter":"1451174400"}
    ] ...
]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Regards, Mario